# Regular expression for URL for Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to set up a goal on Google Analytics and want to match a regular expression against the following url:

> /tasks/[random characters of random length]/complete

An example input url would be:

> /tasks/12444ab22aaa7/complete

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this

```
\/tasks\/[^/]*\/complete
```

Answer (score 2):

^/tasks/.*/complete$

Validate with a search in the Top Content report before using in a filter.